# Do I need to retain properties when using garbage collection?

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection

I'm using garbage collection in Objective-C 2.0. Do I need to retain properties? Eg.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

Or is this enough:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

I initialize the array like this:

```
self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the garbage collector you don't have to care about retaining and releasing if you don't write code that should be compatible with legacy objective-c.

`-(void)retain` and `-(void)release` are empty functions when the GC is on, they don't change the retain count.

This means leaving it out is fine.

Answer (score 2):

retain, release, and autorelease do nothing if the garbage collector is enabled. You can ignore them I believe.